# UPDATED: jquery dialog modal radio button not selected ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-dialog

I have a problem here. I have a jquery modal dialog on which I have 2 radio buttons. In my code I have jQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop handlers to check for Ajax requests (I also have an other jquery dialog pop up to display a Loading... message or something when there is an Ajax request executing). When I select each radio button, an ajax request is made. The problem I am having is that because of the ajax events (ajaxStart, ajaxStop), when I click on the radio buttons, they are not selected (although I get the correct value of my radio button). Any idea what might cause this?

You can see an illustration of what I meean with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTGCF/65/)

Thank you

Comment: Please post some code, or better yet, a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: ok, I'll update with a jsfiddle to illustrate what I'm talking about

Comment: Why do you have ajaxStart and ajaxStop? If you comment out the guts of those functions it seems to work fine.

Comment: I need ajaxStart and ajaxStop to know if there is an Ajax call in progress in order to display my "Loading...." message

Answer (score 0):

Somehow showing the loading dialog is interfering with the click event. If you delay the ajax call with `setTimeout`, it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/jTGCF/66/